# Организация Git repository для решения состоящего из нескольких проектов

Tags: git

Есть проект в котором разработка ведется на основании предметной области(*DDD*).

имеются следующие *слои*:

`DAO`, `DAL`, `Services`, `Gui` где:

- `DAO`, `DAL`, `Services` - это проекты по типу библиотек(*dll*) сгруппированные по функционалу
- `Gui` - ASP.NET-MVC приложение.

Хочу в данном проекте начать использовать систему контроля версий, но не знаю как правильно это сделать, с чего начать, как выстроить структуру? Мне приходит только в голову создание следующей структуры:

```
..\Solution
     \DAO
        ...
     \DAL
        ...
     \Services
        ...
     \Gui
        ...
```

т.е. создаем необходимую физическую структуру каталогов, в соответствующих каталогах размещаем слои и добавляем их под контроль `git`.

Вот только правильно ли так делать.

В качестве среды разработки использую *Visual-Studio 2013 Community*, репозиторий необходим только локально, разработчик только я.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вынести `DAO`, `DAL`, `Services` в отдельные репозитории. Затем с помощью [git submodules](http://help.github.com/submodules/) добавить ссылки на подмодули в репозиторий `Gui`.

Или, если по вашей структуре, то создать еще репозитроий `Solution` и указать подмодули в нем.

Добавлять так:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/user/DAO.git Gui/
```

Comment: Спасибо, если я правильно понял то можно сделать в качестве *submodule* слой DAL - он может использоваться в других решениях.

Comment: а вот остальные слои будут специфичными для текущего решения, насколько коректно выстроить структуру как я указал в вопросе: т.е. `Solution` это каталог решения(директория на диске), в нем подкаталоги `DAO, Services, Gui` надо ли их делать репозиториями или нет?!

Comment: Вполне корректно так сделать. Да, тогда лучше не выносить `DAO`, `Services`, `Gui` в отдельные репозитории.

Comment: и можно последнее уточнение: `DAL` в этом случае будет физически находиться в другом каталоге, и оформлен отдельным репозиторием если я его изменю отразятся ли изменения в текущем решении если будет подключен как *submodule*?!

Comment: Нет, не отразится пока не выполните `git submodule update`, так как создается указатель на определенный коммит.
Можете почитать про [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Инструменты-Git-Подмодули) подробнее.